# jquery on click event

Tags: jquery, события

Есть функционал, который динамически убирает/добавляет товар в корзину, соответственно отображая изменения. Сейчас проблема такова, что после загрузки страницы `->` добавлении товара в корзину `->` убирании этого же товара из корзины `->` повторном добавлении этого же товара в корзину `->` повторное удаление не срабатывает. Пошуршав по сети узнал, что можно привязать событие на дочерний элемент, но мне как раз нужно привязать его к родительскому.

Код такой:

```
 var response = JSON.parse(response);
            $('.box3 .basket .counter').empty().append(response.countBasket);

            var image = response.product.images.split(',')[0];
            var newElement = "";
            newElement += '<li class="basket-list-item" data-id="' + productId + '">';
            newElement +=   '<div class="img-frame">';
            newElement +=      '<img src="/site_media/' + image + '/" alt="">';
            newElement +=   '</div>';
            newElement +=   '<h4 class="title">' + response.product.title + '</h4>';
            newElement +=   '<p>' + response.product.material + '</p>';
            newElement +=   '<span>Quantity: <span class="basket-item-quantity">' + response.product.quantity + '</span></span>';
            newElement +=   '<a class="icons-square-close"></a>';
            newElement +=  '</li>';
            basketList.append(newElement);
```

Само событие:

```
$('.popup-basket a.icons-square-close').on('click', '.basket-list-item', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-id');
var title = $(this).closest('li').find('.title').text();
removeFromTheBasket(id, title);
});
```

В функции `removeFromTheBasket()` просто отображается попап и убирается товар из корзины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, повесил обработчик событий не на `a.icons-square-close`, а на тег `ul.popup-basket`, в котором уже ловил тэг, по которому был клик. Новый код выглядит так:

```
$('.popup-basket').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var target = e.target;
var li = $(target).closest('li');
if(li){
    var id = li.attr('data-id');
    var title = li.find('.title').text();
    removeFromTheBasket(id, title);
}else{
    return;
}
});
```